# React hook form isn't displaying objects in the console onsubmit

Tags: forms, material-ui, react-hooks

I am trying to use react-hook-form to simply generate some data from two material UI text fields and display the data in the console, but the when clicking the submit button I cannot see anything in the console.log, this is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';


const useStyles = makeStyles({
    container: {
       margin: '1rem',
       '& .MuiTextField-root': {
         margin: '1rem 0',

     },
  },
});

const GuestJoiningForm = () => {
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()
const onSubmit = (data) => {
   console.log(data);
};

const classes = useStyles();
return (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className={classes.container}>
       <TextField
       ref={register}
       label="Name"
       name="name"
       variant="outlined"
       fullWidth/>

       <TextField
       ref={register}
       multiline rows={3}
       label="Content"
       name="content"
       variant="outlined"
       fullWidth/>

       <Button
       color="primary"
       variant="contained">Submit</Button>
  </form>
 )
};
export default GuestJoiningForm;
```

When I enter data into the text fields and hit the submit button, nothing happens and I would expect to see an object of the data I enter.  I don't imagine its the console I'm using, but it's in Safari and the only thing I've noticed is something that says [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

Not sure if that has anything to do with it, but would really appreciate any help on this issue if you get time, thank you.

Last thing to add!  I added a type={'submit'} to the button, and the console responded with empty {}, which even though didn't fix the issue I guess proves that the console is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to add `type` attribute as `submit` in the `Submit` button.

```html
<Button type="submit" color="primary" variant="contained">
  Submit
</Button>;
```

2. You need to add `inputRef` prop for both the `TextField` components like this

```html
 <TextField
    ref={register}
    inputRef={register}
    label="Name"
    name="name"
    variant="outlined"
    fullWidth
  />

  <TextField
    ref={register}
    multiline
    rows={3}
    inputRef={register}
    label="Content"
    name="content"
    variant="outlined"
    fullWidth
  />
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-lamarr-r4928?file=/src/App.js) for your form.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So I have made the changes you have suggested and even used the sandbox example (thank you) and seen it works -  unfortunately in my browser though console is only displaying {} with no objects, so quite confused

Comment: Did you add `inputRef={register}` as well ?

Comment: It's now all working! I had added the inputRef={register} as well, but my first attempt was inputref, not inputRef - stupid mistake.  Thank you again!

Comment: Cheers :) @pedrohasabeard

Comment: hey @AjinKabeer, i had same issue as him.. but im using Controller.. your best guest what causes the issue?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-mui-problem-snl78i?file=/src/App.js